# Div appear at > 900px scroll and stop at footer div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble with the following. I have a DIV `single-help` which animates from `-300px` to `0px` when scrolling past `900px` from the top. For which I'm using this code.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var delayms = "900"; // mseconds to stay color
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
            jQuery('.single-help').stop().animate({ bottom: '0px' });
        } else $(".single-help").click(function (e) {
            jQuery('.single-help').stop().animate({ bottom: '-300px' });
                jQuery('.single-help').css('display','none').delay('delayms');
        })
    });
```

This all works, the DIV appears when I scroll past `900px`. But when I reach the footer of the page. It covers the `footer` DIV. Now I'm trying to get the `.single-help` DIV to stop when it reaches the footer. For that I'm using this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
        jQuery('.single-help').stop().animate({ bottom: '0px' });
       $('.single-help').addClass('fixed_button');
   }else{
       $('.single-help').removeClass('fixed_button');
   }
});
```

And this CSS:

```
.fixed_button{
    position:absolute !important;
    margin-top:1900px;
    bottom: 270px !important;
}
```

This stops the DIV from going over the footer content. But, now the problem. When I have reached the bottom of the page and scroll back up, it looks like the code `jQuery('.single-help').stop().animate({ bottom: '0px' });` is being repeated. The DIV `single-help` jumps up to around `300px` and **animates** down back to `0px`. I can't understand for the life of me why this is happening.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or tell me more about why this is happing? And I think this could be done much simpler... Thanks.

I made a fiddle I doesn't work like my site, but it does show that the animation is repeated twice when scrolling up, when you reached the top. https://jsfiddle.net/r31dnqm9/

Comment: what is the result on getting rid of `.stop()`?

Comment: If I remove all the `stop()`s it still does the second animation. So no change... (I removed my comment, because I thought it worked but it didn't).

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu See my Fiddle update in the OP.

Comment: OP means? @Jay-oh

Comment: Opening Post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, sort of. I removed the animation from `-300px` to `0px` and added a fadeIn effect using `opacity`. This works for me, I'll just leave the code out here for future references:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    var delayms = "2000"; // mseconds to stay color
        if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
            jQuery('.single-help').animate({'opacity':'1'},500);
        } else 
        $(".closebutton-footer").click(function (e) {
          $('.single-help').animate({'opacity':'0'},500);
          $('.single-help').css('display', 'none').delay('delayms');
        })
    });
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 250) {
        $('.single-help').addClass('fixed_button');
        } else 
        $('.single-help').removeClass('fixed_button');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about doing some sort of collision detection?  If the element reaches the footer then you change its display..  Here is a simple collision detection script.

```
function CheckDiv()
{
var ediv1 = document.getElementById('DIV1');
var ediv2 = document.getElementById('DIV2');

 ediv1.top = $(ediv1).offset().top;
 ediv1.left = $(ediv1).offset().left;
 ediv1.right = Number($(ediv1).offset().left) + Number($(ediv1).width());
 ediv1.bottom = Number($(ediv1).offset().top) + Number($(ediv1).height());

 ediv2.top = $(ediv2).offset().top;
 ediv2.left = $(ediv2).offset().left;
 ediv2.right = Number($(ediv2).offset().left) + Number($(ediv2).width());
 ediv2.bottom = Number($(ediv2).offset().top) + Number($(ediv2).height());

if (ediv1.right > ediv2.left && ediv1.left < ediv2.right && ediv1.top < ediv2.bottom && ediv1.bottom > ediv2.top)
 {
alert("hi");
}

if (ediv1.left > ediv2.left && ediv1.top > ediv2.top && ediv1.right < ediv2.right && ediv1.bottom < ediv2.bottom)
 {
alert("hello");
    }
}
```